# Subsonic 3: Calling Stored Procedures as functions in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, orm, subsonic, subsonic3

It seems that the only way to call an Sp with Subsonic 3 is as follows:

```
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("NameOfSP");
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyVar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
```

I remember some time ago that it was possible to call a stored procedure as a function:

```
SPs.NameOfSP(1);
```

Is this still possible with SubSonic? If not, what SP wrapper would provide this functionality?

Comment: It should be possible. What version of Subsonic 3 are you using? is it 3.0.0.0 or 3.0.0.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a T4 template named "StoredProcedures.tt" that generates the methods to match your stored procedures. If that file is missing, you can re-fetch it from [here](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/blob/master/ActiveRecord/StoredProcedures.tt).
The way the template is currently set up, the method takes in the parameters and sets them for you, then returns a `StoredProcedure` object instance, and I think you might have to call `.Execute()` on it, like:

```
SPs.NameOfSP(1).Execute();
```

but you could easily modify that T4 template to call .Execute() within the SP method call.